# rails routing by id with reserved models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to have short URLs using an :id of one particular model instead of :model/:id.

I know how to make the :id work using a match

```
match ":id" => "artist#show", :as => :artist
```

That works fine, assuming of course i am careful with keeping somethings reserved, ie new/index/edit etc.

But how can I then also keep other models working when no :id matches?  IE /label or even /artist/new

I also would like to further do this with nesting so I also have... :artist_id/:album
is there some easy way to deal with nested routes with custom paths?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to the precedence of each route. If you put all of your more-specific routes above your short-url route in routes.rb, they will be matched first. If nothing more specific matches, Rails will route it to artist#show.

You will probably want to take care to show a relevant error if no artist exists for the given ID, given that someone might not have been looking for an artist and would instead expect a generic 404 if there was an error.

Comment: i didn't realize it was in order of preference in the route file and I had it at the top before thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to match only `/\d+/` ? You can guard route matching with such constraints. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints

```
match ":id" => "artist#show", :as => :artist, :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }
```